# Selenium with C#

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am new to C# with selenium and visual studio,I have some experience only in Selenium with java in eclipse.

Here my doubt is that in eclipse we used to configure the packages for every new projects but we are not going to download each and every time, but in Visual studio it requires to download packages for every new projects.

Is this the only way or is there any other way to do, as like in the selenium?

Answer (score 2):

The standard package manager for C# / .Net is NuGet

[image]

More details on the setup and management process for Visual Studio [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem faced by any engineer of testing company who is new to Visualstudio.

In C# we are not going to download dependencies for each project.
When we load the project in visual studio and Click 'Build' > 'Build Solution'. This will download missing dependencies.

Moreover in C# we used to install dependencies only while creating a project. From here on we need to perform 'Rebuild Solution' or 'Build Solution' only